# Issue installing sharepoint foundation 2010 in windows 7. Error: "The language of this installation package is not supported by your system"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, sharepoint-2010

Following the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx I tried to setup development environment for SharePoint 2010 in Windows 7(64 bit) machine. After installing all the prerequisites mentioned and enabling the windows features, I moved to install SharePoint 2010. I am having SharePoint foundation 2010 and when I run the setup.exe am getting an error:

> "The language of this installation package is not supported by your system"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to go through this [SharePoint 2010 "The language of this installation package is not supported by your system"](http://techblurt.com/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2010-the-language-of-this-installation-package-is-not-supported-by-your-system/)

[Following the instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx) works. No need to re-gurgitate… however this little supposed “unsupported language” problem cropped up… well I should really have RTFM, try to install [install the hotfix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=23806&wa=wsignin1.0) before running the configuration wizard.

More Reference:
[Install Sharepoint 2010 in a non Server OS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155805/Install-Sharepoint-2010-in-a-non-Server-OS)

Hope this help.

Comment: saved me a lot of headaches today :)

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the zip file using WinRAR rather than windows default extractor.
it worked for me.